# Router history with react-router 4.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In `react-router 4.0.0` the history provisoning seems to have changed, with the following `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I get:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

and an error afterwards. I browsed the code but can't find any example or API how that has changed.

Answer (score 29):

React Router v4 changed things little bit. They made separate top level router elements. Replace `<Router history={hashHistory}>` with `<HashRouter>` in your code.

Hope this will help full.

```
import {HashRouter,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

<HashRouter>
    <Route path = "/getapp" component = {MainApp} />
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I wonder why the akser didn't marked it as right!

Answer (score 9):

`hashHistory` is no longer an exported object of `react-router`. If you want to use a hash history, you can just render a `<HashRouter>`.

```js
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render((
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>
), holder)
```

Comment: And how would that work for BrowserROuter and why are there no paths defined?

Comment: You would just replace `<HashRouter>` with `<BrowserRouter>`. The `<Route>`s would be rendered inside of the `<App>` component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic where RR documentation should add more clarity... To answer your question, you can either use a [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter), or you can use a Router and pass it a [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) instance.

Go with the first approach when all your route changes are through Link components.

However, when you need to change routes from your store methods, you would need to use the latter approach. You can write a module which creates and exports a history object and then use the same object in your Router component and in the store methods. It's important to use the same object otherwise the Router won't be able to correctly sync the URL changes with your store.

Comment: I think they are just rewriting the whole docs? All the previous docs have been removed

Answer (score -6):

You may try the code below:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
  <App/>
</Router>
```

Check the [doc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Router.md) here.